# How can I use FileUpload control just to get the file name and avoid posting the file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload

I just need the name of the file, but when I click the save button it kinda uploads the file (big files will produce an exception) and I don't want the page to "try" to upload the file.

Markup:

```xml
<asp:FileUpload runat="server" ID="txtPDFPath" />
```

Code Behind:

```cs
Reference r = new Reference() { R_CatalogNumber = txtCatalogNumber.Text.ToLower(), R_PDFPath = txtPDFPath.FileName.ToLower() };
```

Comment: Related: [Browse for file window without uploading the file](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10322936/242)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the workaround I figured out was to use a simple 'input type="file"' and a asp textbox with 'Style=""display:none"' and with some javascript set the text of the textbox to the file input value, note that you will get c:\fakepath\filename so you can use the Path class to get just the file name... it wokrs perfectly...